# Converting from string to user defined object. Class cast exception

Tags: java, binary-tree

Tree Class:

```
public class Tree {

    String data;
    Tree left,right;

    public Tree(String data, Tree left, Tree right){
        this.data = data;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

Another Class containing a particular method:

```
public static void evaluateDecisionTree(String s){
    //String s is a post-fix converted expression.
    String tokens[] = s.split(" +");
    Stack tree_stack = new Stack();
    Tree root;

    for(int i=0; i < tokens.length; i++){

        if(tokens[i].matches("[-]?[0-9][0-9]*")){
            tree_stack.push(tokens[i]);
        }
        else if(tokens[i].equals("!")){
            tree_stack.push(new Tree(tokens[i], (Tree) tree_stack.pop()));
        }
        else{
            tree_stack.push(new Tree(tokens[i], (Tree) tree_stack.pop())); //line 138
        }

    }
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to Tree
>     at In2Post.evaluateDecisionTree(In2Post.java:138)
>     at In2Post.main(In2Post.java:59)

Question:

> I know we cannot convert a String to an Object. Is there a way to achieve what I am doing ? I cannot change the constructor parameter to String as it would defy my logic in building a decision tree.

Comment: It's not clear from your post what code is at line 138 of In2Post.java file which is the location of the exception.

Comment: Sorry. I just edited my question, including line no. 138 as comment. line 59 is just calling the method from main.

Comment: Define a proper constructor with the input of a string, then creates an object of tree class and get the string as an input to it.

Comment: @Aashil Your `Tree` constructor takes a string and two trees and you are calling it with two strings. `tree_stack` contains strings ... casting them into Tree is not going to automatically convert them. You really need to get your Tree constructors straight.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert a String into a Tree, as the stack object contains the String objects returned from the split(). And a java.lang.String IS NOT a Tree.

Comment: I know. I was asking the alternative solution to my problem. Nevermind. I solved it.